# Getting running aplication WebUI::WebUIApplication and adding an EventHandler

Tags: windows-runtime, cordova-plugins, winjs, c++-cx

I'm trying to add an EventHandler to my Windows Runtime application, but doing something like:

```
CxHelper^ cxHelper = ref new CxHelper();
auto activatedEventHandler = ref new Windows::UI::WebUI::ActivatedEventHandler(cxHelper, &CxHelper::WindowActivated);

Windows::UI::WebUI::WebUIApplication::Activated += activatedEventHandler;
```

Will simply crash the application, here is the CxHelper header:

```
public ref class CxHelper sealed
{
public: 
void WindowActivated(Object^ sender, Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::IActivatedEventArgs^ eventArgs);
}
```

For grabbing the CoreApplication from XAML applications I'd usually do:

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::GetCurrentView();
```

And then add the events I need, but for this specific case I have no idea what to use, how do I get the WebUIApplication to work?

I know I can also do it from the WinJS using *WinJS.Application.activated*, but I need that trigger to work within my WINRT component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I initialize the plugin I create my own Task (using std::thread) and from inside it I was trying to add the *EventHandler* to the *WebUI::WebUIApplication*, but apparently **it doesn't work unless I do it directly from the plugin main thread**, everything works as it should now, I only had to read the exception carefully to realize what was wrong.